Mention all in a message using skypy
I'm using Python's skypy module to send Skype messages. I'd like to "mention all" in a message. How can I do this with the API?
This is my attempt so far:
from skpy import Skype

SKYPE_EMAIL = 'user'  # Your Skype email address
SKYPE_PASSWORD = 'pass'  # Your Skype password  
TOKEN_FILE = "tokens.txt"
skype = Skype(SKYPE_EMAIL, SKYPE_PASSWORD, tokenFile=TOKEN_FILE)
RECIPIENT_ID = '19:5af466d66de6439bb7c44d6ce33ea7c7@thread.skype'
message = "Hello Group Members"

skype.chats[RECIPIENT_ID].sendMsg(message,'<at id="*">all</at>', rich = True )

